# bootstrap grid not spacing properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the fiddle I am working on right now
http://codepen.io/trippygif/pen/KVWYdV

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <div id="title-list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#heading">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-me">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work-heading">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="title">
  <div id="heading">
<h1>AN OPEN PERSPECTIVE</h1>
</div>
  <div id="list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reddit</a></li>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="about">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 id="about-me" class="to-fit title-font">About Me</h2>
      <p id="interests" class="span4">I am a self taught web developer with      a degree in physics from the University of Colorado Boulder. I have strong interests in web design and development as well as mathematics.</p> 
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <p>My Proficiencies</p>
     <ul>
       <li>#1</li>
       <li>#2</li>
       <li>#3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
  </div>


  <div class="work">
    <div id="work-heading" class="to-fit title-font">
      <h1>Work</h1>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contact">
    <div id="work-heading" class="to-fit title-font">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Basically I am having trouble with the Bootstrap alignment that occurs in the "about" div. I cannot seem to get the paragraph on the left side of the page and the list on the right side of the page. I assume something might be wrong with my CSS. Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want the "About Me" and the list to start in the same vertical hight?

Comment: no I would prefer to have the About Me title at the top of the div and then have the paragraph and the list be on the same vertical height

Comment: I was able to figure it out by putting the About Me title inside one of the columns. Looks good now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the "About Me" heading and the list doesn't start in the same vertical height, then you have to do something with your `.to-fit` CSS rule where you set a `padding-top : 80px;`.

Just give a properly sized top padding or margin to your right block:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:120px;">
    <p>My Proficiencies</p>
    ...
```

or

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:120px;">
    <p>My Proficiencies</p>
    ...
```

Of course you can/should place this rule to a CSS rule with a selector of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

change class `container` to`container-fluid`

```
    <div class="menu">
  <div id="title-list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#heading">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-me">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work-heading">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="title">
  <div id="heading">
<h1>AN OPEN PERSPECTIVE</h1>
</div>
  <div id="list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reddit</a></li>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="about">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 id="about-me" class="to-fit title-font">About Me</h2>
      <p id="interests" class="span4">I am a self taught web developer with a degree in physics from the University of Colorado Boulder. I have strong interests in web design and development as well as mathematics.</p> 
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <p>My Proficiencies</p>
     <ul>
       <li>#1</li>
       <li>#2</li>
       <li>#3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
  </div>


  <div class="work">
    <div id="work-heading" class="to-fit title-font">
      <h1>Work</h1>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="contact">
    <div id="work-heading" class="to-fit title-font">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried to implement the container-fluid class but I did not notice any changes to the original behavior.